# Learning to implement a Linked List Queue in C++

Tags: c++, list, hyperlink, queue

I would like to implement a linked list using queue in C++. Here is my class:

```
class LinkedListQueue
{
public:
    LinkedListQueue();
    void enQueue(int x);
    void deQueue();
    int peekFront();
    int peekBack();

private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};


LinkedListQueue::LinkedListQueue()
{
    tail = 0;
    head = tail;
}
void LinkedListQueue::enQueue(int x)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = tail;
    tail = newNode;
    if(head != NULL)
    {
      head = tail->next;
    }
}
void LinkedListQueue::deQueue()
{
    struct Node* newTail = tail->next;
    delete m_tailPtr;
    tail = newTail;
}
int LinkedListQueue::peekFront()
{
    if(tail != NULL)
  {
    return tail->data;
  }
  else
  {
    return head->data;
  }
}
int LinkedListQueue::peekBack()
{
  if(head != NULL)
  {
    return head->data;
  }
  else
  {
    return tail->data;
  }
}
```

I think my functions are working except for the peekFront. I would like to keep the implementation and style the same, just fix the error. Please help.

Comment: You've edited your question but **still haven't stated what your error is**. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, your `NULL` checks aren't any good when both `head` and `tail` are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain what the error is but if you access `peekFront` with an empty `LinkListQueue` instance then the `tail` pointer will be `NULL`. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (as `peekFront` does) will cause ***undefined behavior***.

There may be other call sequences which also involve calling `peekFront` with a `NULL` `tail` pointer.

### Edit

You also shouldn't be mixing `malloc` with `delete`. Use `new` with `delete` (or `malloc` with `free` if you insist).

Answer (score 1):

> You don't explain what the error is but if you access peekFront with an empty LinkListQueue instance then the tail pointer will be NULL. Dereferencing a NULL pointer (as peekFront does) will cause undefined behavior.

Same situation with `LinkedListQueue::peekBack()`. Seems that `head` is set to `0` in constructor and never modified.

**Edit**

When adding first element to list you can check if `head == tail == 0`. In such case newly added element if the first one, both `head` and `tail` should probably point to it.

**Edit**

First of all: adding first node to list must be handled differently to next elements, it should set both: `head` and `tail` to newly added element. It could be done like this:

```
void LinkedListQueue::enQueue(int x)
{
    struct Node* newNode = new Node;

    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = 0;

    //first element in list
    if( head == 0 )
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
}
```

Second thing: the list is one-directional (each node contains link to `next` one, no link to previous node). It means that dequeueing must iterate through all nodes starting from `head` to modify the `next` link of node before `tail`:

```
void LinkedListQueue::deQueue()
{
    struct Node* node = head;

    // single element in list
    if ( node == tail && node != 0 )
    {
        delete node;
        tail = 0;
        head = 0;

        return;
    }

    while( node->next != tail )
    {
        node = node->next;
    }

    delete tail;
    node->next = 0;
    tail = node;
}
```

**Edit**

Assuming that `peekFront` takes node data from first node:

```
int LinkedListQueue::peekFront()
{
    if( head == NULL ) 
    {
        throw out_of_range("trying to peek data from empty list");
    }

    return head->data;
}
```

And `peekBack` takes node data from last node:

```
int LinkedListQueue::peekBack()
{
    if( tail == NULL ) 
    {
        throw out_of_range("trying to peek data from empty list");
    }

    return tail->data;
}
```

Comment: And one more thing... `LinkedListQueue` needs destructor, which will properly destroy all of the nodes.

Comment: thanks. could you share how you would implement peakForward and peak Backward?

Comment: Example implementation in edited answer. `<stdexcept>` must be included to use `out_of_range` exception from `std`.

Answer (score 0):

head is never set after being initialized to 0.  You also lack logic to deal with cases when head = tail, when the first item is added, or last item removed.

Comment: I have modified head and set functions to deal with null values, but it still does not work properly... Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: pstanisz gave a really detailed answer.  So much so that I stopped reading 1/4 way through, but up to that point he was spot on!

The thing is you really need to go through the logic better.  you have basic behavior, but some edge cases, like adding to an empty list, and removing the last item from a list.  Write this out on paper, draw a few diagrams of how nodes behave under each operation.  It becomes far easier to implement.  Until you understand everything you have to provide you are wasting your time trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void LinkedListQueue::enQueue(int x)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = tail;
    tail = newNode;  

    if( head == null )
    {
       head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: based on this implementation, the other functions must also be changed, because this is not giving me the proper list

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).